# Is there a way I can stick this into a for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I updated the code to use for loops, and an arrayList for the buttons. now it has given me an error.

java.lang.NullPointerException

BlueJ editor is pointing to this line.

```
for(int i=0; i<=buttonsList.size(); i++){
```

I think it has something to do with instance variables not existing or something before the arrayList. Also, it compiles perfectly, but when I run main, it then goes back to the line in the code!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

//Created class the extends JFrame, and implements action listener
public class Board extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
//Instance variables 
private JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, reset;
private ArrayList<JButton> buttonsList;

//'playerO' uses the letter 'O', not the number zero
Icon playerO = new ImageIcon("images/playerO.jpg");
Icon playerX = new ImageIcon("images/playerX.jpg");
Icon playerN = new ImageIcon("images/reset.jpg");

//Instance variable to determine player turn
boolean firstPlayer = true;

//Constructor
public Board()
{
    //Title of Frame
    super("Gui7 - TicTacToe || Jose Reyes");

    //Created container and set the layout
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //Created a panel, and set the layout
    JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();
    gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    //Created new JButtons and added them to the array list 
    for(int i=0; i<=buttonsList.size(); i++){
        JButton jBut = new JButton(playerN);
        buttonsList.add(jBut);
    }

    //Created reset button and title
    reset = new JButton("Play Again?");

    //Added buttons to panel with for loop
    for(int i=0; i<=buttonsList.size(); i++){
        gridPanel.add(buttonsList.get(i));
    }

    //Added panel and reset button to container
    c.add(gridPanel);
    c.add(reset, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    //Added Action Listeners with loop
    for(int i=0; i<=buttonsList.size(); i++){
        buttonsList.get(i).addActionListener(this);
    }

    //Added action listener to reset button
    reset.addActionListener(this);

    //Set the window size and set visibility
    setSize(600,600);
    setVisible(true);
}

//ActionEvents
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    //Grab source
    Object src = e.getSource();

    for (int i = 0; i<=buttonsList.size(); i++){
        if(src == buttonsList.get(i)){
            if(firstPlayer){
                buttonsList.get(i).setIcon(playerO);
                firstPlayer = false;
            } else {
                buttonsList.get(i).setIcon(playerX);
                firstPlayer = true;
            }
        }
    }


    //Reset button icons with loop
    if(src == reset){
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            buttonsList.get(i).setIcon(playerN);
        }

        firstPlayer = true;
    }

}

//Main method
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Board t = new Board();
    t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: You're cheating yourself by not trying to do this yourself first. Why not -- you've nothing to lose. And if in the attempt it doesn't work, you can post a much better more complete question, one with your attempt.

Comment: Use an array of buttons instead. And then iterate the array to test `src` against button in the array. And yes, you could use a `for` loop.

Comment: I havee tried for hours, that is why I am here. The array idea sounds good though, but I think I will have to change alot becasue currently I have to refer to the buttons to add them to the JFrame, and addAction listeners to them. I will try, thanks!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I realize that you've "tried for hours" -- I'm asking you to **show your attempts**. Surely that's not asking too much of you, is it? Otherwise the question comes across somewhat as a lazy beg for code, and I know that you can do better than this.

Comment: Oh, Thanks. I misunderstood. I thought you said that I just commented without trying myself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this with a for loop.

First, store all your buttons in an array or arraylist. Since the other answer is an array, I'll do arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Button> buttonsList = new ArrayList<>();
buttonsList.add(b1);
buttonsList.add(b2);
```

etc. Then,

```
for (Button b: buttonsList){
    if (src == b) {
        if (firstPlayer) {
            b.setIcon(playerO);
            firstPlayer = false;
        } else {
            b.setIcon(playerX);
            firstPlayer = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I suggest you just use an arraylist instead of array. Its much easier to work with since you don't need to specify a size before hand.

Instead of this line:

```
private JButton buttons[];
```

Do

```
private ArrayList<Button> buttonList = new Arraylist()<>;
```

Additionally change,

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        buttons[i] = new JButton(playerN);
}
//do this instead
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    JButton jBut = new JButton(playerN);
    buttonsList.add(jBut);
}

//Added buttons to panel with for loop
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    gridPanel.add(buttons[i]);
}
//Do this instead
//Added buttons to panel with for loop
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    gridPanel.add(buttonsList.get(i));
}
```

**EDIT2:**
This is almost definitely causing one of your problems lol

```
//Added Action Listeners with loop
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    buttons[1].addActionListener(this);
}
```

You are adding the listener to the second button- buttons[1] every time. Change that to buttons[i].addActionListener(this); and it will probably work.

Comment: Hey, I have tried these loops, and i did it for all my buttons, but its throwing an error. How can I show you my updated code???

Comment: Hey, I did this, can you find the problem??? Someone said I didnt initialize, but I think I did with a for loop, i filled the array with buttons.

Comment: This is probably easier to do with an arraylist since you are adding to it. See my edit.

Comment: I think I discovered your crash, check edit 2. If so, check mark this answer!

Comment: Hey I will check plus if you can fix this. I already changed everything to arrayList, and everything was coming along great, but it is still giving me that stupid java.lang.NullPointerException . I think it has to do with the creation of the new buttons, and the instance variables at the top named b1, b2 .etc I am not sure. I will edit so you can see what I have now. Thanks!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136025/discussion-between-pinocho-2010-and-walter-morawa).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than have a bunch of variables named `b1`...`b9`, make an array of whatever type `b1` is. Then you can iterate over the array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    if(src == bArray[i]){
       if(firstPlayer){
          bArray[i].setIcon(playerO);
          firstPlayer = false;
       } else {
          bArray[i].setIcon(playerX);
          firstPlayer = true;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this!

Comment: You generally want to avoid posting more than a statement or two in comments. You may want to edit your original post. You could try to make it fit in a comment though.

Comment: You aren't ever initializing the array.

Comment: hey, what do you mean??

Comment: for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            buttons[i] = new JButton(playerN);
        }

Answer (score 0):

something like below should work.

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9]; // i'll leave you to fill it

for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){ // assuming the array is filled
 if(src == buttons[i]){
   if(firstPlayer){
      buttons[i].setIcon(playerO);
      firstPlayer = false;
   } else {
      buttons[i].setIcon(playerX);
      firstPlayer = true;
   }
 }
}
```